# Clion:Using functions with the same name as built-in C functions causes conflict

Tags: c, linux, cmake, clion

I wanted to edit the files of repository 
"https://github.com/mit-pdos/xv6-public"
inside Clion but the project contains some functions with the same names as built-in C functions. 
And I get warning messages like:

`warning: conflicting types for built-in function ‘strlen’`
for a user-defined function like:
`int strlen(const char*);`

By the way:
Clion generates a folder called "cmake-build-debug" inside my project directory that when I delete it and run make on a terminal it works fine but when I run make with that folder it gives conflict warnings and errors that weren't there before.

I somehow need to delete dependency of built-in C libraries for my project to work correctly, but I dont know how.

Comment: Do you get the warning inside CLion itself, from its inline code analysis? Or do you get the warning when you *build* your program?

Comment: As for the `cmake-build-debug` directory, it's the CLion *build* directory, where it runs the `cmake` program and puts all output files. It's generally recommended that you don't build inline in the source or main project directory.

Comment: Lastly, there are flags for GCC (and Clang) to not look for standard header files or libraries. You probably need to add those to your `CMakeLists.txt` file.

Comment: I used the Qemu plugin to build it and that's where I got these errors and warnings